# Creating Django 1.6 URLs with unicode characters using Python 3

Tags: django, url, python-3.x, unicode

I've installed Django 1.6 and setup Gunicorn with Python 3.3. Everything works fine together as far as I can tell.

I'm trying to get a URL to look like this: `web.com/piña`. I've started an app with `python3 manage.py startapp pina` and created a super basic view.

```
# pina/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('¡Hola mundo! Esta es mi primera vista.')
```

I've also added a new URL entry like this.

```
# django_project/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from pina import views
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^pi%C3%B1a/', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

But when I visit `web.com/piña/`, I get a 404 page.

[image]

The `/admin/` URL works just fine. If I change `r'^pi%C3%B1a/'` to just `r'^pina/'`, that also works—but that's a different word entirely.

Comment: So why can't you just put `piña` in the urls.py?

Comment: Wow. It's really that easy? I'm so used to struggling to write an `ñ`, I guess I didn't try that. Thanks!